# ElasticSearch rails : order results by object's associated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have implemented Searchkick in a rails app and it is working fine. I want to order my results based on the number of associated objects.
For Eg. If I am searching for users by their name, then I want to order the results by the number of followers. (User having most followers should come first)

```
@users = User.search "2% #{query}", include: [:followers], fields: [:name]
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add counter cache (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html 4.1.2.3) and use `followers_count` column on `User` model to order it.

```
User.search "2% #{query}", include: [:followers],
            fields: [:name], order: followers_count
```